# Why can't I check if ViewModel properties in view == null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Simple question (Ihope), I want to check if a property in my ViewModel is null using an if statement in the View

```
@if(Model.AdminPractice.TimeNotes == null)
```

this cause's an error,

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

However the if statement works if if I don't call the property itself and just the class.

```
@if(Model.AdminPractice == null)
```

Is this because the Viewmodel is a combination of classes rather then properties or should I be handling this in the controller if so how ?? thanks

View model...

```
public class AdminPracticeViewModel
{
    public Practice Practice { get; set; }

    public AdminPractice AdminPractice { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is because `Model.AdminPractice` **is** `null`. What you need to do is this:

```
@if(Model.AdminPractice == null || Model.AdminPractice.TimeNotes == null)
```

Comment: Wouldn't your code still throw? You should do the Model.AdminPractice check _before_ the Model.AdminPractice.TimeNotes one.

Comment: Surely that will still throw an error if Model.AdminPractice is null?

Comment: @jods: that's correct but if you reverse the order of the checks this should work perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error because you are trying to access a property value of a null object. In this case `AdminPractice` is null, and trying to access any of its properties will give you this error.

You will need to propulate AdminPractice in the controller before sending it through to the view.

So by changing your if statement to that of below your code will work:

```
@if(Model.AdminPractice == null || Model.AdminPractice.TimeNotes == null)
{
    // Do whatever you need to do here
}
```

I hope this helps.